# Javascript - Set Text When Accordion Expands/Collapses

Tags: javascript, css, accordion

I have a JavaScript accordion type menu. I want to have an indicator in front of the menu section headers that shows (+) when the section is collapsed and (-) when it is expanded. Based on the code below, I've been able to this, however the indicator only changes on click and is not set based on whether the section is expanded or collapsed. I've been looking at this for a few hours now and would appreciate any extra eyes that may be able to figure out the logic that is escaping me.

[Here's a JSFiddle (Click Me)](http://jsfiddle.net/kUXuY/)
Here's the Javascript:

```
var ContentHeight;
var TimeToSlide = 250.0;
var opening;
var openAccordion = '';

function runAccordion(index, height)
{
  ContentHeight = height;
  var nID = "Accordion" + index + "Content";
  if(openAccordion == nID)
    nID = '';

  setTimeout("animate(" + new Date().getTime() + "," + TimeToSlide + ",'" 
      + openAccordion + "','" + nID + "')", 33);

  openAccordion = nID;
}
function animate(lastTick, timeLeft, closingId, openingId)
{  
  var curTick = new Date().getTime();
  var elapsedTicks = curTick - lastTick;

  opening = (openingId == '') ? null : document.getElementById(openingId);
  var closing = (closingId == '') ? null : document.getElementById(closingId);

  if(timeLeft <= elapsedTicks)
  {
    if(opening != null)
      opening.style.height = ContentHeight + 'px';

    if(closing != null)
    {
      closing.style.display = 'none';
      closing.style.height = '0px';
    }
    return;
  }

  timeLeft -= elapsedTicks;
  var newClosedHeight = Math.round((timeLeft/TimeToSlide) * ContentHeight);

  if(opening != null)
  {
    if(opening.style.display != 'block')
      opening.style.display = 'block';
    opening.style.height = (ContentHeight - newClosedHeight) + 'px';
  }

  if(closing != null)
    closing.style.height = newClosedHeight + 'px';

  setTimeout("animate(" + curTick + "," + timeLeft + ",'" 
      + closingId + "','" + openingId + "')", 33);
}
function changeText(index){

    var accordionID = "Accordion" + index + "Content";
    var indicatorID = document.getElementById("expandIndicator" + index);
    var currentIndicator = indicatorID.innerHTML;
    var openIndicator = "(+)";
    var closedIndicator = "(-)";

    if (currentIndicator == openIndicator) {
        indicatorID.innerHTML = closedIndicator; }
    else {
        indicatorID.innerHTML = openIndicator; }
}
```

And here is the HTML/CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #container {
        padding-top:5px;
    }

    .stepHeader, .AccordionContent, .AccordionContainer
    {
      position:relative;
      width:735px;
    }

    .stepHeader
    {
      /*height:25px;*/
      overflow:hidden;
      cursor:pointer;
      color:black;
      font: 12px "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
      text-transform:uppercase;
      vertical-align:middle;
      text-align:left;
      display:table-cell;
      -moz-user-select:none;
      border-bottom:solid #FFFFFF;
      padding:5px;
    }

    #step1 {
      background-color:#FF7F32;
    }

    #step2 {
      background-color:#ff8a43;
    }

    #step3 {
      background-color:#ff9454;
    }

    #step4 {
      background-color:#ff9f65;
    }

    #step5 {
      background-color:#ffa976;
    }

    #step6 {
      background-color:#ffa976;
    }

    .AccordionContent
    {
      height:0px;
      overflow:auto;
      display:none; 
      background-color:#f8f8f0;
    }

    .AccordionContainer
    {
        padding:0 0px 0 5px;
    }

    .expandIndicator {  
        width:15px;
        display:inline;
        margin-right:5px;
    }

    .stepTitle {
        width:400px;
        display:inline;
    }
</style>

<div id="container">
            <div id="AccordionContainer" class="AccordionContainer">

              <div onclick="runAccordion(1,100);">
                <div class="stepHeader" id="step1" onselectstart="return false;" onclick="changeText(1)">
                  <div id="expandIndicator1" class="expandIndicator">(+)</div> 
                  <div class="stepTitle">Step 1</div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div id="Accordion1Content" class="AccordionContent">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
              </div>

              <div onclick="runAccordion(2,100);">
                <div class="stepHeader" id="step2" onselectstart="return false;" onclick='changeText(2)'>
                  <div id="expandIndicator2" class="expandIndicator">(+)</div>
                  <div class="stepTitle">Step 2</div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div id="Accordion2Content" class="AccordionContent">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
              </div>

              <div onclick="runAccordion(3,100);">
                <div class="stepHeader" id="step3" onselectstart="return false;" onclick='changeText(3)'>
                  <div id="expandIndicator3" class="expandIndicator">(+)</div>
                  <div class="stepTitle">Step 3</div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div id="Accordion3Content" class="AccordionContent">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
              </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So, are you trying to set it on initial page load? Do other events sometimes cause expand/collapse? I'm not exactly sure that I understand what the problem is.

Comment: i created a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZkNgk/5/, but i didn't 'get' your code, so I suggest using jQuery UI, if your requirements allow it. edit: http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/. edit: it will take 20 minutes tops to download and use.

Comment: JSager - When the page loads, all Steps are set to (+). When you click Step 1, it expands and the + should change to - for Step 1. When you click Step 2, Step 1 collapses, Step 2 expands. At the same time, Step 1 - should change to Step 1 + and Step 2 + sould change to Step 2 -.

Comment: Ah ok. So, mindandmedia has the right idea imho. Is there anything stopping you from using jQuery and jQuery UI? You'd get better value out of your time solving business problems than attempting to debug someone else's handrolled JavaScript widget. If not, I'll try to help, but jQ is the way to go.

Comment: I've never used jQuery UI and not sure how long it would take me to re-code this. There are 36 sections to the actual menu. Was hoping for a solution using what code is already in place.

Comment: Did you try my solution below? I tested it and it worked for me.

Comment: Worked when setting variables individually, but not with the loop.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is set all the indicators to '+' in the changeText method before doing anything else. Add the following code **before the if statement** in the changeText method:

```
document.getElementById("expandIndicator1").innerHTML = openIndicator;
document.getElementById("expandIndicator2").innerHTML = openIndicator;
document.getElementById("expandIndicator3").innerHTML = openIndicator;
```

Or, if you have too many content divs:

```
var numberOfContentDivs = 36;
for ( var i = 1; i <= numberOfContentDivs; i++) {
    document.getElementById("expandIndicator" + i).innerHTML = openIndicator;
}
```

Comment: Hrm, for some reason it worked when setting the variable value individually, but not with the loop.

Comment: Make sure the numberOfContentDivs is correct. It could fail silently if it is not.

Comment: Also, if I click on Step 3 before clicking on anything else, the Step 3 indicator changes to - as expected; however, if you click Step 3 after already clicking Step 1 or 2, Step 3's indicator does not change.

Comment: In other words, use 36 only if you have 36 divs. Otherwise, use the correct number of content divs you have.

Comment: Ah, ok... now what would cause the Step 3 indicator to intermittently change?

Comment: It's working perfectly for me. I am not getting the error you describe. If you click on Step 1 and then on Step 3, you end up with Step 1 closed with a plus and Step 3 expanded with a minus. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: That's correct, but Step 3 isn't always changing to a minus when expanded. Only sometimes.

Comment: You're killing me paper doll! LOL